# Async task and soap Android

Tags: android

I need to get the value of mango and orange from the xml below using android background service.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<soap:Body><wsFruitResponse xmlns="http://www.orange.ws/fruitspec/ws">

<mango>wow</mango>

<orange>boom</orange>

</wsFruitResponse>

</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

Then it should be stored in an array list. How can i achieve this. I am used to regular sax parser but this soap thing look weird. Please help

class loadingTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        ...
        sh.parseContent("");
        return "";

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        ShowProgress.dismiss();

    }
}

class SAXHelper {
    public HashMap<String, String> userList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private URL url2;

    public SAXHelper(String url1) throws MalformedURLException {
        this.url2 = new URL(url1);
    }

    public RSSHandler parseContent(String parseContent) {
        RSSHandler df = new RSSHandler();
        try {

            ....
            xr.setContentHandler(df);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(url2.openStream()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return df;
    }
}

class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private Post currentPost = new Post();

    StringBuffer chars = new StringBuffer();

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) {

        chars = new StringBuffer();
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("orange")
                && currentPost.getOrange() == null) {
            currentPost.setOrange(chars.toString());

        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("mango")
                && currentPost.getMango() == null) {
            currentPost.setMango(chars.toString());

        }

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
            PostList.add(currentPost);
            currentPost = new Post();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
    }

}
```

Comment: the xml: 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<soap:Body><wsFruitResponse xmlns="http://www.orange.ws/fruitspec/ws">

<mango>wow</mango>

<orange>boom</orange>

</wsFruitResponse>

Comment: Please frame your question in a more professional way and you may get some answer.

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @Deestan i have updated my question please check what i've done

Comment: have u used `Jsoup` parser to get the value of mango and orange ? @yakusha

Comment: @Shoshi what is Jsoup :O ?

Comment: r u getting this xml after a webcall ? @yakusha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**N.B:** this is using Jsoup. [Download Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/packages/jsoup-1.7.2.jar), paste it to your project libs folder.

you can try something like this:

```
URL form = new URL(Your_url_String);
HttpURLConnection connection1 = (HttpURLConnection)form.openConnection();
connection1.setRequestProperty("Cookie", your_cookie);//if you have no cookie, you can skip this line

connection1.setReadTimeout(10000);
StringBuilder whole = new StringBuilder();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(connection1.getInputStream())));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
     whole.append(inputLine);
     in.close();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(whole.toString());
Element element1 = doc.select("mango");
Element element2 = doc.select("orange");

String value_of_mango = element1.text();
String value_of_orange = element2.text();
```

**Update:**

u can do for your soap like : Remember, u have to input `soap` as string.

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
  + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element element1 = doc.select("mango");
Element element2 = doc.select("orange");

String value_of_mango = element1.text();
String value_of_orange = element2.text();
```

Comment: URL form = new URL(Your_url_String); ? can i put the soap content in your_url_string please ?

Comment: hello dude, can you help me please i have some issue with jsoup. Is Jsoup compatible with android 4.0 to latest and secondly, how can i store the data in an arraylist meaning if there are several information. By the way, can we have this discussion in private chat ? thanks