# display a listView using Activity(not ListActivity) and asyncTask onPostExecute() android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When I run my application it crashes. Actually I noticed that the problem appears when I write `list.setAdapter(adapter);` in `PostExecute()`. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

In `Searchbykey` activity the user can choose some items from list

```
public class Searchbykey extends SherlockActivity {

    ActionBar actionbar;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    double latitude, longitude;
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> xml_results;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog; 
    Intent intentResults ;
    int k=0;
    //XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ENV = "environment"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_FEED = "feed";
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_LAT = "lat";
    static final String KEY_LON = "lon";
    static final String KEY_DIF_LAT = "dif lat";
    static final String KEY_DIF_LON = "dif lon";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

    String[] countries = new String[] {
            "India",
            "Pakistan",
            "Sri Lanka",
            "China",
            "Bangladesh",
            "Nepal",
            "Afghanistan",
            "North Korea",
            "South Korea",
            "Japan"
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.keylist);

        actionbar=getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setTitle("Search by keyword(s)");

        //-------Get the location that calculate from previus acrivity. Before that activity start. 
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) 
        {
            System.out.println("None");
        }

        //Get data via the key
        latitude = extras.getDouble("latitude");
        longitude = extras.getDouble("longitude");


        //----------I have a location service that detect the location and send a broadcast msg. So here I declare a register to listen the broadcast msg for location

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("xxx.yyy.intent.action.LOCATION");
        this.registerReceiver(new LocationReceiver(), filter);

        //The checkbox for the each item is specified by the layout android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);

        //Getting the reference to the listview object of the layout
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);

        //Setting adapter to the listview
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.keywordmenu, menu);

        (menu.findItem(R.id.search)).setIcon(R.drawable.action_search);
        (menu.findItem(R.id.clear)).setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_clear);

        //return(true);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:

            //-----------Call new activity that appears the search result   
            intentResults = new Intent (this, Keysearch_results.class);
            startActivity(intentResults);

            break;
        case R.id.clear:
            ClearSelections();
        break;
        }
        return true;

    }    
}

//-----The Keysearch_results is the activity that i want to take info from url (xml parser) and appear the result of search
public class Keysearch_results extends SherlockActivity {

    //XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ENV = "environment"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_FEED = "feed";
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_LAT = "lat";
    static final String KEY_LON = "lon";
    static final String KEY_DIF_LAT = "dif lat";
    static final String KEY_DIF_LON = "dif lon";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";


    public ProgressDialog progressDialog; 
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItems;

    //Menu Bar
    ActionBar actionbar;

    //List
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    //User Location
    double latitude, longitude;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.results);

        //Appear action bar
        actionbar=getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setTitle("Results");


        //Getting the reference to the listview object of the layout
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ResList);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems,
                R.layout.result_row,
                new String[] { "feed", "dif lat",}, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.dif});

   new YourDownload().execute();

    }


private class YourDownload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

     // private String Content;


     @Override
     protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

         if(isOnline()){
            listItems.clear();   
            int i; 
            HashMap<String, String> map = null; 
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            //getting XML
            String xml = null ;
          DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            try {
                request.setURI(new URI("http://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds.xml?&key=Sov51TAorgtao6W_JuNodPN3KMqSAKxuZjFsblR3TUp4TT0g&lat=35.1446170529352&lon=33.3462524414062"));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.print("http\n");
            }
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            try {
                httpResponse = client.execute(request);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            try {
                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            //getting DOM element
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); 

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ENV);
          //int size=nl.getLength(); 
            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_FEED, parser.getValue(e, KEY_FEED));
                map.put(KEY_DIF_LAT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LAT));
                map.put(KEY_DIF_LON, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LON));
                listItems.add(map);
            }
         }
         else{
            Toast.makeText(Keysearch_results.this, "No connection..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
        }

            return 1;
        }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

         if(result==1 && listItems!=null)
         {

         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         }
         progressDialog.dismiss();
         super.onPostExecute(result);
     } 

    }
}
```

List layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView android:id="@+id/name" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
  </TextView>

   <TextView android:id="@+id/dif" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp" > </TextView>

   <TextView android:id="@+id/dd" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
  </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Errors:

```
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795): Activity com.example.ioaaan.Searchbykey has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.ioaaan.Searchbykey$LocationReceiver@40cdb248 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.example.ioaaan.Searchbykey has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.ioaaan.Searchbykey$LocationReceiver@40cdb248 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:795)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:596)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1316)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1296)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1290)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:423)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at com.example.ioaaan.Searchbykey.onCreate(Searchbykey.java:121)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Sorry for all that errors but i am new in android application and I can not understand how to fix the errors

Comment: plz also add logcat results with question to get more help from us.

Comment: You could create a pop up dialog with the listView, is that okay?

Comment: What kind of array list is myList? ArrayList<?>?

Comment: public  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;

Comment: The pop up dialog appear until doInBackground done its process. Yes, it's ok

Comment: 04-06 14:37:50.754: W/ActivityManager(280): Force finishing activity com.example.ioaaan/.Test 04-06 14:37:51.614: W/ActivityManager(280): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{410c8da0 u0 com.example.ioaaan/.Test} Is that help? It appeared many errors:/

Comment: 04-06 16:15:35.348: E/AndroidRuntime(789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 16:15:35.348: E/AndroidRuntime(789): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup That is the exception that i take

Comment: 04-06 16:15:35.348: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:121)
04-06 16:15:35.348: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
04-06 16:15:35.348: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
04-06 16:15:35.348: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
04-06 16:15:35.348: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)

Comment: post your Logcat error in your question. it is really hard to understand these error  in comment

Comment: which is the line number 121 in your  Searchbykey.java class ?

Comment: line 121: this.registerReceiver(new LocationReceiver(), filter); Its a register for a service

Comment: i think your problem is in `LocationReceiver`, if it is possible, please provide your full code.

Comment: sry for the delay i was tring to write some explanations

Comment: @loanna : i have posted an answer. check it out. let me know is it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

to register and unregister  `BroadcastReceiver` try this:

**1.**

```
//declare this as global in your class.
private LocationReceiver locationReceiver = new LocationReceiver();
```

then in your `OnCreate()`

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("xxx.yyy.intent.action.LOCATION");    
this.registerReceiver(locationReceiver, filter);
```

then in `OnDestroy()` unregister `locationReceiver` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (locationReceiver != null) {
        locationReceiver.cancel(true);
    }
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(locationReceiver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**2.**
if it doesn't help then delete your `LocationReceiver` class and declare bellow variable, which will work same as `LocationReceiver`:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver locationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent calledIntent)
         Log.d("LOC_RECEIVER", "Location RECEIVED!");

         latitude = calledIntent.getDoubleExtra("latitude", -1);
         longitude = calledIntent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", -1);            
    }
};
```

then in your `OnCreate()`, register `locationReceiver` like this:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("xxx.yyy.intent.action.LOCATION");    
this.registerReceiver(locationReceiver, filter);
```

then in `OnDestroy()` unregister `locationReceiver` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (locationReceiver != null) {
        locationReceiver.cancel(true);
    }
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(locationReceiver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

hope this will help. By the way, i have used 2nd approach in my project.

Comment: what problem ? are u getting new error ? in your logcat error (which you have posted in your question) `04-06 19:50:30.326: E/ActivityThread(795):  at com.example.ioaaan.Searchbykey.onCreate(Searchbykey.java:121)` idicate that the problem is in line no: 121. and you said that line 121 is: `this.registerReceiver(new LocationReceiver(), filter);` in your comment. are you getting new error. if yes , post them

Comment: by the way, where are you calling `GetDataTask` ?

Comment: i changed the activities. The xml parser is in Keywords_result activity. Here AsyncTask class called YourDownload.

Comment: oo, oo, oo, hold on a second buddy. u r continuously changing your question. that's not good. first u asked something else. now u r asking something new. what r u trying to say? from your error log (in your question's comment) , it was `SimpleAdapter` problem. then u post something new error in your question, which indicate the problem is about `LocationReceiver`. now u r asking another thing which is related with `XML Parsing`. r u tryung to get all your answer within one question ? that's not good.

Comment: check my answer here for your last question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655935/async-task-and-soap-android/15658035#15658035

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I did not try to get all answer with one question. My problem was the AsyncTask. I solved it. Actually i have problem with list layout. Thank you very much for your time.